# How to see if a function called is originated from PHP die()

Tags: php

I have a php function `create_error($error_string, $priority = false, $display_error = "")`

`$error_string` = Error Message.

`$priority` = If the function should only display this message above all other messages. `create_error` uses a global variable to store all the previous error messages in an array. If `$priority === true` then it will just have the new message in the array else it will have the new message added using `array_push`.

`$display_error` = Control to highlight along side the error message.

```
function create_error($error_string, $priority = false, $display_error = "")
{
    global $json_responder;

    if ($priority === true) {
        $json_responder = array(array("typeof" => "message", "message" => translate($error_string)));
    } else {
        if (count($json_responder) >= 1) {
            array_push($json_responder, array("typeof" => "message", "message" => translate($error_string)));
        } else {
            $json_responder = array(array("typeof" => "message", "message" => translate($error_string)));
        }
    }

 // my ideal if died statement would be here.
 // like 
 // if(is_from_die() === true){
 // echo json_encode($json_responder);}
 }
```

I have the following piece of code:

```
$sql_code = "select username, password, login_allowed from user where current = 1 and username = '$username' and password = '$password' ";
$qrs = mysqli_query($sql,$sql_code) or die(create_error('E500.2 - internal server error.'));

if(mysqli_num_rows($qrs) >= 2 || mysqli_num_rows($qrs) === 0) die(create_error('Incorrect username / password combination.'));
```

So when this code runs `die(create_error('Incorrect username / password combination.'));` it doesn't ever display the message because it never gets to the end of the function.

How can I determine in my `create_error` function if it was called from a `die` construct in PHP?
I've tried `debug_print_backtrace();` which returns

```
Array
    (
        [0] =&gt; Array
            (
                [file] =&gt; C:\Web\dev\core\request_initializer.php
                [line] =&gt; 83
                [function] =&gt; create_error
                [args] =&gt; Array
                    (
                        [0] =&gt; Incorrect username / password combination.
                    )

            )

        [1] =&gt; Array
            (
                [file] =&gt; C:\Web\dev\core\request_initializer.php
                [line] =&gt; 29
                [function] =&gt; request_login
                [args] =&gt; Array
                    (
                    )

            )

    )
```

Is it possible to detect weather it came from a `die()` construct?
I have a lot of work around options here because the application is still in the core development stages, but my ideal option would be for PHP to "automatically" detect the `die()` or `exit()`

Comment: Looks like a job for [`register_shutdown_function`](http://php.net/register-shutdown-function). You won't be able to tell if it was a `die()` that killed it, but your code will at least do something.

Comment: can you share with us th eimplementation of function create_error(...); ?

Comment: And what would you do differently if you detected the `die`? BTW, it gets to the end of the function just fine. The execution order is `create_error()`, then `die()`. The solution is simple: use a better error handling mechanism than `die`. Throw an exception for example. `return false`. *Anything* except simply killing the script.

Comment: or wrap `die()` in a custom fuction, and store the fact that it was called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really advice you to use Exception, and that you implement you Custom Exceptions instead of calling `exit()` or `die()` built in functions...
Otherwise, now, the only way to achieve your work, is by changing your code like this :

```
$qrs = mysqli_query($sql,$sql_code) or create_error('E500.2 - internal server error.', FALSE, "", TRUE);


function create_error($error_string, $priority = false, $display_error = "", $withExit = FALSE) {
    // do your stuf...
    // ...
    if($withExit === TRUE) {
        exit (0);
    }
}
```